# Tidyverse Select function does not keep the unnamed columns of an unclass item

Tags: r, select, filter, tidyverse, tidyr

How can I filter EFA factors to include items that have only the items having loadings greater than a certain threshold?

I used *fa* function. 
Here is a reproducible code:

```
bfi_cor <- cor(bfi_data)
bfi_data=bfi_data[complete.cases(bfi_data),]
factors_data <- fa(r = bfi_cor, nfactors = 4)
```

I unclassed the factor loadings as such:

```
df_EFA <- data.frame(unclass(factors_data$loadings))
```

Here is the head of the output:

```
           MR1          MR2          MR3           MR4
A1 -0.23768598  0.068096644  0.032857014  0.0007631509
A2  0.55855557  0.096152392  0.090485457 -0.0438972912
A3  0.65067617  0.068763169  0.040190930 -0.0215080952
A4  0.44606746 -0.007382889  0.181278979 -0.1956348388
```

I would like to create a data frame for, say MR2, to include only items that have loadings greater than or equal to 0.4

```
MR2_cutoff=df_EFA%>%filter(MR2>=0.4)%>%select(MR2)
```

So far so good but when I run this, I lose the column with the corresponding items listed on the first column.

```
MR2
<dbl>
0.7455404               
0.7393464               
0.7572845               
0.5704315               
0.5713734
```

But, I want to keep the item names such as A1, A2, A3, A4.
Is it a feature in the 'filter' or 'select' function that I need to make sure to keep those corresponding item names?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: don't use `select`. Try `df_EFA %>% filter(MR2>=0.4)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I don't use select, I will have all the factors. If If I select only a specific column, say MR2, by using (df_EFA)$MR2, then this does not include the items of the first column; in other words, itt only gives the MR2 values rather than both MR2 and corresponding items (such as A1, A2, C1,C2). Now, I wonder if I miss anything super obvious.

Comment: can you edit your post to include `dput(head(df_EFA))` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem primarily is in the unclass as the df_EFA dataframe contains "row name" of valuable information, in general it is always better to convert the row name into a column.

So my recommendation for you is to convert rowname into column and if you want it to be row name again to reconvert it later.

The following code should do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create dataframe of values
df_EFA <-
  data.frame(
    MR1 = c(-0.23768598, 0.55855557, 0.65067617, 0.44606746),
    MR2 = c(0.068096644, 0.096152392, 0.068763169, -0.007382889),
    MR3 = c(0.032857014, 0.090485457, 0.040190930, 0.181278979),
    MR4 = c(0.0007631509, -0.0438972912, -0.0215080952, -0.1956348388),
    row.names = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
  )
```

There are two ways with which you can use rowname, one is using tibble and another using Base R.

Using tibble

```
df_EFA %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% # To convert rownames into a column
  filter(MR2 >= 0.04) %>% # Do required filtering
  select(rowname, MR2) %>% # Select only needed variables
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "rowname") # (Optional convert column into rowname again)
```

Using Base R

```
data.frame(names = row.names(df_EFA), df_EFA) %>% # To convert rownames into a column
  filter(MR2 >= 0.04) %>% Do required filtering
  select(names, MR2) %>% # Select only needed variables
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "names") # (Optional convert column into rowname again)
```